# Vue.js PrimeVue 2.10.1 DataTable Filtering

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I am using PrimeVue for the DataTable component.

I am trying to use the Filter function of the component where every column has a filter function with the values of the similar to what is on [this table's column "Agent"](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/datatable/filter) except in this example they are using a static array with objects that have unique values.

I am adding the filter values dynamically where the value is what exists in the rows. This causes an issue has it uses all the values in the rows which duplicates it.

A way around I found was to store all the values into a Set to only get unique values and then use these for the filter selection but this seems like a bandaid issue as when filtering one column, the other column's filter list doesn't update to only have filter values based on the updated table rows.

Is there a native way to have the component show a filter value list of the unique values it has in its rows?